# Book wherein all transactions are logged and transactions/popularity funds a space mission

Tags: story-identification, books

I have searched, but come up empty. I did not read this book, but I read about it or was told about it -- TBH, I believe it maybe that someone described it to me in a chat room and so I read it in that sense. I believe I was informed about the story within the last handful of years (2014-2018) and that it is making me think it was published in/around 2000.

From what I recall being told, the book's basis is about how all transactions are logged as there are electronic tags on most all things. Transactions, IIRC, can be varied in terms of what that means, but I took it to mean any thing traded or services rendered. Somehow popularity plays a part in this. There is a spaceship on a long term mission that is funded by these transactions and popularity (on Earth?). This popularity funds the daily operation of the ship. However, the plot twist is that something on Earth changes or in that population so that people either start to forget about the mission or that it becomes less popular. Because of this, less funds, and thus resources, go to help power the ship on this voyage. This causes the ship to start to fail... and that's the main gist of what I remember being told or having read a review/summary of..

What made it memorable to me was that the ship started to fail and that was dependent on the popularity of the mission. This premise made me think of many other possible projects or "missions" that could also be started due to some burst of interest.. but, with our quick-to-move-on minds, quickly interest wanes and causes their demise.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to fully understand how our site works. You've provided a fair amount of information about the work you're looking for, but you still may want to look at the answer to [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) It may make you think of info you wouldn't have included on your own. For instance: from the question, this is a book you read *about*, not one you've actually read; when did you read about it? Do you remember where you read about it? This may help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the help @RDFozz !

Comment: There is a story, by Niven I believe, about a spaceship years out in space and now in trouble, and a rescue mission needs to be launched. But this mission has to be funded, and the general populace doesn't really care about the crew any more and doesn't want to spend much money on them, so much of the story is about how to make the spaceship more popular.

Comment: Someone not on SFF.SE mentioned to me that it might be "Neptun's Brood" from Stross. I am not sure, but the notions about economics of space travel seem on point.

Comment: @MrLister Ooh, that sounds interesting.. Any thoughts on which of Niven's books it might be?